# Changing project directory brightway2 to import projects

Tags: brightway

I have a question related to importing projects via the bw2io.backup.restore_project_directory(filepath) function. I'm trying to import the project into a different location than the standard directory, but I cannot get it to work.

I already tried changing the BRIGHTWAY2_DIR as described here (https://documentation.brightway.dev/en/latest/source/faq/data.html). This however is not working. I also tried changing the default directory via bw.set_data_dir('filepath', permanent = True) but I get the following error message:

---

NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[12], line 1
----> 1 bw.set_data_dir('D:\brightway_folder_SESAM', permanent =True)

File D:\program_files\envs\ab\lib\site-packages\bw2data\utils.py:308, in set_data_dir(dirpath, permanent)
300 def set_data_dir(dirpath, permanent=True):
301     """Set the Brightway2 data directory to `dirpath`.
302
303     If `permanent` is `True`, then set `dirpath` as the default data directory.
(...)
306
307     """
--> 308     warnings.warn("`set_data_dir` is deprecated; use `projects.set_current('my " 309                   "project name')` for a new project space.",
310                   DeprecationWarning)

NameError: name 'warnings' is not defined